# Is the value of a constexpr in C++(11) always guaranteed to be "calculated" at compile-time when assigned to a const var?

Tags: c++11, constants, metaprogramming, constexpr

I wrote a deep recursive constexpr-function which does a lot of calculation. Although I assigned its return-value to something like this:

```
const int test = recursiveFunction(number);
```

I'm pretty sure that the value of my function is *not* calculated at compile time, because my program compiles happily with absolutely no errors or warnings, but it crashes when executed.

Hint: I realized, that if that function goes not that *deep* (when "number" is low for example), the program runs with no problems.

Comment: Try `constexpr int test = recursiveFunction(number);`, but `number` needs to be a compile-time constant.

Comment: Use `constexpr`, not `const`. Preferably use the result in a constant expression to trigger it, e.g. `static_assert`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To test this:

```
constexpr int recursiveFunction(int); // define somewhere

constexpr int number = 42; // or any other compile-time constant
constexpr int test = recursiveFunction(number);
static_assert(test == expected, "");
```

You might want to tweak the Clang compiler option `-fconstexpr-depth=N` which sets the limit for recursive `constexpr` function invocations to `N`. The default is 512. Another limit you might run into is `-fconstexpr-steps` which does not have a documented default.

Answer (score 2):

The compiler *may* evaluate a constant expression at compile time if it chooses, when runtime evaluation would also be possible. However, an expression which exceeds an implementation limit such as `constexpr` recursion depth (or otherwise incurs undefined behavior) ceases to be a constant expression. Then the compiler is required to abort the evaluation and compile it for runtime instead. (It's possible that runtime recursion would not have crashed. To prove the function is really defective would be solving the halting problem.)

You can force compile-time evaluation by initializing a variable declared as `constexpr`. This specifically forbids runtime initialization, so if `constexpr` aborts you get a hard error.